# How to use an environment variable of a remote host using scp?

Tags: ssh, environment-variables

I have two machine, host1 and host2.

I would like to use an environment variable of host2, from a scp command from host1. For instance, use this kind of command from host1 :

```
scp file host2@host2_adress:$FOO
```

where $FOO is defined in host2 as the path of a directory. If I am using the command above, bash will search among the variables of host1 and not host2.

A practical example would be to use the $HOME variable of host2

How to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
scp file host2@host2_address:$(ssh host2@host2_address 'printf $FOO')
```

In order to resolve the value of the variable `$(ssh host2@host2_address 'printf $FOO')`, the shell will internally execute the command `ssh host2@host2_address 'printf $FOO'`, and take whatever this command prints as the value of the variable, which is then substituted into the outer `scp` command. It is, of course, clear that you have to *fetch* the variable `$FOO` from host2, because host1 simply does not know it. One way to fetch it is using `ssh` as in the above command.

Mind:

1. You have to have some kind of public-key authentication working, so that the inner `ssh` command works without any further user input. Otherwise, because of the inner `ssh` and the outer `scp`, you would be prompted for the password twice.
2. You should ensure that the inner `ssh` command prints out nothing but the variable `$FOO`. Try it out on its own before using it in the outer `scp` command and make sure it works.
3. For some reason I do not fully understand, when I tested the command that I wrote above, it would not work as expected because the fetched variable would contain some weird control prefix. For instance, when I tried to copy something to the remote `$HOME`, it would try yo copy it to `\033k$HOME\033\\/home/user` instead of simply `/home/user`. I had to use the following to get it to work:

   ```
   scp file host2@host2_address:$(ssh host2@host2_address 'printf $FOO' | cut -d\\ -f2)
   ```

   ...where `$FOO` was `$HOME` in my particular case, of course.

This is a quick (as it's rather short) and dynamic (as it will fetch the variable on the fly) solution I came up with. However, particularly because of the last point, I think it would be more reliable to have a script that fetches the remote variables by first printing them to a file. More precisely, that script on host1 would connect to host2, remotely print the output of `printenv` to some file at host2, fetch that file from host2, parse it, and export the values to local environment variables. For example, the variable `$FOO` on host2 could be put into a variable `$HOST2_FOO` on host1. The following script would do this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh host2@host2_address  'printenv > host2_vars.txt'
scp host2@host2_address:host2_vars.txt .
#ssh host2@host2_address  'rm host2_vars.txt' #if you like to clean up
eval $(cat host2_vars.txt | perl -pe 's/^(.*)=(.*)$/export HOST2_$1="$2"/g')
```

Of course, you would have to execute that script *before* the `scp` command.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest escaping the dollar

```
scp file host2@host2_adress:"\$FOO"
```